# Как исправить ошибку net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)?

Tags: php, backend

Пишу spa на vue + бекенд на php
На open server все работало нормально, но когда я загрузил приложение на реальных хостинг то на любой запрос к беку появляется ошибка
GET http://andre8d9.beget.tech/api/controllers/auth.php net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)

Бек и фронт находятся в одной директории, вот что прописано в .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Вот функция аутентификации

```
  async auth() {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/api/controllers/auth.php');
      if(response.data == 'Ok') {
        return true
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('User not authorized', error);
      return false
    }
  },
```

Вот бекенд

```
<?php
  class DataBase {
    public static function connectDB() {
      $mysqli = new mysqli
      (
        'localhost',
        'root',
        '', 
        'task_list' 
      );
      if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        die('Ошибка соединения' . $mysqli->connect_errno);
      }
      return $mysqli;
    }
  }
?>


<?php
  require '../database/DataBase.php';
  require '../utils/Validate.php';

  class User {
    public function signup() {
      $requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
      $requestBody = json_decode($requestBody, true);

      $resName = Validate::validateName($requestBody['name']);
      $resEmail = Validate::validateEmail($requestBody['email']);
      $resPassword = Validate::validatePassword($requestBody['password']);

      if(!$resName || !$resEmail || !$resPassword) {
        die('Ошибка валидации');
      }

      $mysql = DataBase::connectDB();

      $name = $requestBody['name'];
      $email = $requestBody['email'];
      $password = $requestBody['password'];
      $authKey = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));


      $prepare = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (name, email, password, auth_key) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
      $prepare->bind_param('ssss', $name, $email, $password, $authKey);

      $prepare->execute();
      $prepare->close();
      $mysql->close();
      echo 'Ok';
    }

    public function login() {
      $requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
      $requestBody = json_decode($requestBody, true);


      $mysql = DataBase::connectDB();
      $prepare = $mysql->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ? AND `password` = ?");
      $prepare->bind_param('ss', $requestBody['email'], $requestBody['password']);

      $prepare->execute();

      $result = $prepare->get_result();

      if($result->num_rows) {
        $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['user']['id_user'] = $user['id_user'];
        $_SESSION['user']['auth_key'] = $user['auth_key'];

        echo 'Ok';
      } else {
        echo 'wrong login or password';
      }

      $prepare->close();
      $mysql->close();
    }

    public function auth() {
      if($_SESSION['user']) {
        echo 'Ok';
      } else {
        echo 'user not authorized';
      }
    }

    public function logout() {
      if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['user']);
        session_destroy();
        echo 'Ok';
      } else {
        echo 'error';
      }
    }
  }

?>
```

Вот гит хаб проекта
https://github.com/AndreyDevWork/TaskList

Пытался пошаманить над .htaccess но ничего не помогло

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)